# Set Hidden Items to True for certain roles

Tags: content-editor

I'm trying to set hidden items to true for a certain role. There's a very similar question [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2288/1436). I thought this might be a caching issue so I tried setting `UserOptions.View.ShowHiddenItems` how it is set [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530132/2597149) but that didn't work out either.

After setting the value both ways I tried manually reloading all my site's registries and I also tried using `user.Profile.Reload()` to see if that would update the value of `UserOptions.View.ShowHiddenItems` to be true but that didn't work out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After drilling down further in the code I found the issue. The property `ShowEntireTree` returns what is saved in the registry straight up while `ShowHiddenItems` returns `false` if it is false otherwise it returns whether or not the user can read the item in the core db that relates to the hidden item checkbox (`/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View/Hidden Items`).

Giving my role read access to that made the solution [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2288/1436) work as expected.